# Converting datatable to int directly in c#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, command, int

I tried to convert a datatable that just has one field (the field's data is primary key) to int , in order to using in sql commands such as Select and etc.
but it fails!
and when i cast it to an object or convert it to string first , the commands gone wrong!
please help me

---

i want to select * from a table which has a foreign key where the foreign code equals by an int value that has been selected from a table in another sql command and returned as a datatable row with just one field.

here is my code :

**class mydata** :

```
public string strsql;
        public DataTable showData()
        {
            SqlConnection Con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;database=daneshgah;integrated security=true");
            Con1.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strsql, Con1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Con1.Close();
            return (dt);

        }
```

**button event :**

```
    myData search = new myData();
                int aa = int.Parse(txt_stdcourse.Text);
                search.strsql = "select tchNo from University where couNo='" + aa + "'";
                DataTable a = search.showData();
                 string b = a.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    int c = int.Parse(b);
                    myData akhz = new myData();
                    akhz.strsql = "insert into stc (couNo,tchNo,stuNo)values('" + aa + "','" + c + "','" + id + "')";
                    akhz.Data();
                    lbl_stdcourseok.Visible = false;
                    lbl_stdcourseok.Visible = true;
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing. Please also include the information about the error you are getting.

Comment: Put some code with your question of what you have tried. Also how you ended up with a single value in a data table, may be you are loading it up through database using `DataAdapter`. Consider using `ExecuteScalar` which would return you a single item.

Comment: Change it in your database.

Comment: I'm guessing ( since you didn't provide code ) that you are trying to convert a row or bunch of rows - or maybe an entire table into an int, please provide code , or better yet - use the debugger to see exactly what value you are attempting to cast into an int

Comment: Are you using SqlParameter?

Comment: How can you expect us to help you when you have not provided what the error is, or the code...

Comment: no i dont use sqlparametr

Comment: dear overmind i try to dont change it in DB

Comment: because of i have not 10 reputition i cant post the source until 8 hours! wtf is this?!

Comment: guys i put it in my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) on a SqlCommand instead of using a DataAdapter. ExecuteScalar gives the first column of the first row of the dataset returned.

```
public object RunSQL(string sql)
{
    SqlConnection Con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;database=daneshgah;integrated security=true");
    Con1.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strsql, Con1);
    return command.ExecuteScalar();
}

//In some event handler
int myValue = (int)RunSQL("Select Value from Table where ID = " + ID);
```

That said, please don't do that - it is very bad practice. You almost certainly want to create a class that models whatever data objects you are dealing with, instead of executing arbitrary SQL from event handlers. It is also probably best to manage connections independently of your data class, in a separate [data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer).

An extremely rudimentary example:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public bool CurrentlyEnrolled { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static Student LoadByID(int ID)
    {
        DataTable results = DAL.ExecuteSQL("Select * from Students WHERE StudentID = @StudentID", new SqlParameter("@StudentID", ID));

        if (results.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            return FillFromRow(results.Rows[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new DataException("Could not find exactly one record with the specified ID.");
        }
    }

    private static Student FillFromRow(DataRow row)
    {
        Student bob = new Student();
        bob.CurrentlyEnrolled = (bool)row["CurrentlyEnrolled"];
        bob.Name = (string)row["Name"];
        bob.StudentID = (int)row["StudentID"];
        return bob;
    }
}

public static class DAL
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "SomeConnectionString"; //Should really be stored in configuration files.

    public static DataTable ExecuteSQL(string SQL, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable result = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(result);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a good idea but its a class that would may return something else such as string and char...

Comment: Well, you could give the method a return type of object and then have the caller cast it into the desired type, but having an essentially static method that runs non-paramaterized queries with a hardcoded connection string is almost certainly a bad idea anyway.

Comment: See my revised answer - I've included an example, and an example of a somewhat more proper way to do it.